# How to renormalize RDBMS to NoSQL with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rdbms, join, nosql

I want to data from RDBMS to NoSQL. I created the first graph, I've found end tables. *I found end nodes, I want to add to the table they belong.* But I couldn't so. I must found Primary Key and Foreign Key on the tables. Only I must join tables. *What can how I do in Node.js?*